# Combine column values in an R dataframe all at once

Tags: r

Is there a way to combine R data columns with other columns all at once?

For example,

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A","B"), b = c("d","f"), c = c("x","y"))
asd
```

```
  a b c
1 A d x
2 B f y
```

Expected output (combine column 'a' with *both* column b and c):

```
  a  b  c
1 A Ad  Ax
2 B Bf  By
```

Comment: This question does not show enough effort, so why is it considered as a test to see if people are paying attention?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `paste0` with the first column `asd[[1]]` and the unlisted other columns `unlist(asd[-1])` and assign it back in the `data.frame` in place of the other columns `asd[-1]`.

```
asd[-1] <- paste0(asd[[1]], unlist(asd[-1]))
#  a  b  c
#1 A Ad Ax
#2 B Bf By
```

Disable `recursive` and `use.names` in `unlist` might improve the perfomance:

```
asd[-1] <- paste0(asd[[1]], unlist(asd[-1], FALSE, FALSE))
```

The same but using names:

```
S <- c("b", "c")
asd[S] <- paste0(asd$a, unlist(asd[S]))
```

Another way is to use `paste0` in `Map` and subset `asd` once with `[-1]` excluding the first column and `[rep(1,2)]` getting the first column 2 times.

```
asd[-1] <- Map(paste0, asd[rep(1,2)], asd[-1])
```

The same but using names:

```
S <- c("b", "c")
asd[S] <- Map(paste0, asd[rep("a", length(S))], asd[S])
```

Another way will be to use a `for` loop;

```
for(i in 2:3) {asd[[i]] <- paste0(asd[[1]], asd[[i]])}

for(i in c("b", "c")) {asd[[i]] <- paste0(asd$a, asd[[i]])}
```

---

Comparing the methods:

```
getDf <- function(nr, nc) { #function to creat example dataset
    data.frame(a = sample(LETTERS, nr, TRUE),
               setNames(replicate(nc, sample(letters, nr, TRUE), simplify=FALSE), paste0("b", seq_len(nc))))
}

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
M <- alist(
    unlist = (function(asd) {asd[,-1] <- paste0(asd[,1], unlist(asd[,-1], FALSE, FALSE)); asd})(D)
  , Map = (function(asd) {asd[-1] <- Map(paste0, asd[rep(1,ncol(asd)-1)], asd[-1]); asd})(D)
  , "for" = (function(asd) {for(i in 2:ncol(asd)) {asd[[i]] <- paste0(asd[,1], asd[,i])}; asd})(D)
  , "for+str_c" = (function(asd) {for(i in 2:ncol(asd)) {asd[[i]] <- str_c(asd[,1], asd[,i])}; asd})(D)
  , lapply = (function(asd) {asd[-1] <- lapply(asd[-1], function(x) paste0(asd$a, x)); asd})(D)
  , across = (function(asd) {asd <- asd %>% mutate(across(-a, ~str_c(a, .x))); asd})(D)
  , pmap = (function(asd) {asd <- asd %>%
  pmap_dfr(~ c(list(...)[1], setNames(paste(..1, c(...)[-1], sep = ""), names(asd)[-1]))); as.data.frame(asd)})(D)
  , "row+matrix" = (function(asd) {asd[-1] <- paste0(asd$a[row(asd[-1])], as.matrix(asd[-1])); asd})(D)
  , apply = (function(asd) {asd[-1] <- apply(asd[-1], 2, function(x) paste0(asd[[1]], x)); asd})(D)
)
```

```
D <- getDf(1e5,2) #1e5 rows and 2 columsn
bench::mark(exprs = M)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 unlist     29.07ms 29.92ms    29.5     12.68MB    11.8     15     6      509ms
#2 Map        22.94ms 23.02ms    42.6      1.53MB     1.94    22     1   516.38ms
#3 for        22.84ms 22.96ms    42.8      1.53MB     1.94    22     1   514.15ms
#4 for+str_c   9.78ms    10ms    97.2      1.53MB     3.97    49     2   503.89ms
#5 lapply     22.89ms 23.01ms    42.7      1.53MB     1.94    22     1   514.82ms
#6 across     12.29ms 12.57ms    77.8      1.53MB     1.99    39     1   501.43ms
#7 pmap         2.95s   2.95s     0.339    9.54MB     6.45     1    19      2.95s
#8 row+matrix 30.64ms 32.65ms    19.8     14.97MB     6.09    13     4   656.35ms
#9 apply      32.93ms 34.12ms    27.7     19.55MB     5.94    14     3   504.85ms
#Warning message:
#Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
```

```
D <- getDf(1e2, 1e3)
bench::mark(exprs = M)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 unlist      21.4ms  21.7ms     45.2    18.08MB     9.68    14     3      310ms
#2 Map           28ms  28.1ms     35.3    12.53MB     4.41    16     2      453ms
#3 for         39.3ms  39.4ms     25.4      8.5MB     2.11    12     1      473ms
#4 for+str_c   34.1ms  34.3ms     29.1      8.5MB     4.48    13     2      447ms
#5 lapply      21.9ms  22.1ms     44.7    12.48MB     7.46    18     3      402ms
#6 across      80.3ms  80.9ms     12.3     5.98MB     4.93     5     2      406ms
#7 pmap       113.9ms   114ms      8.74    17.5MB     5.83     3     2      343ms
#8 row+matrix  24.5ms  24.6ms     40.2    19.31MB    10.7     15     4      373ms
#9 apply       32.3ms  32.5ms     30.5    21.72MB    11.1     11     4      360ms
```

Regarding Memory usage `across` and the `for`-loop could be recommended. Regarding speed in case of two rows `Map`, `for` and `lapply` in case of 1000 rows `unlist` and `lapply` so overall `lapply` could be recommended. Also using `str_c` instead of `paste` could improve performance.

---

In case all columns have the same type it could be considered to store the data in a `matrix` what will show advantives in case of many columns.

```
M <- as.matrix(asd)

M[,-1] <- paste0(M[,1], M[,-1])

M
#     a   b    c   
#[1,] "A" "Ad" "Ax"
#[2,] "B" "Bf" "By"
```

```
D <- getDf(1e5,2)
M <- as.matrix(D)
bench::mark(check = FALSE #One gives a data frame the other a matirx
 , lapply = (function(asd) {asd[-1] <- lapply(asd[-1], function(x) paste0(asd$a, x))})(D)
 , lapplyStr_C = (function(asd) {asd[-1] <- lapply(asd[-1], function(x) stringr::str_c(asd$a, x))})(D)
 , matrix = (function(M) {M[,-1] <- paste0(M[,1], M[,-1])})(M)
 , matrixStr_C = (function(M) {M[,-1] <- stringr::str_c(M[,1], M[,-1])})(M)
)
#  expression      min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr>  <bch:t> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 lapply       28.3ms 28.8ms      34.7    1.53MB     0       18     0      519ms
#2 lapplyStr_C  13.6ms 13.9ms      71.6    1.53MB     2.05    35     1      489ms
#3 matrix       34.1ms 34.4ms      28.9    7.25MB     7.24    12     3      415ms
#4 matrixStr_C  17.8ms 18.2ms      53.9    7.25MB     7.35    22     3      408ms
```

```
D <- getDf(1e2, 1e3)
M <- as.matrix(D)
bench::mark(check = FALSE #One gives a data frame the other a matirx
 , lapply = (function(asd) {asd[-1] <- lapply(asd[-1], function(x) paste0(asd$a, x))})(D)
 , lapplyStr_C = (function(asd) {asd[-1] <- lapply(asd[-1], function(x) stringr::str_c(asd$a, x))})(D)
 , matrix = (function(M) {M[,-1] <- paste0(M[,1], M[,-1])})(M)
 , matrixStr_C = (function(M) {M[,-1] <- stringr::str_c(M[,1], M[,-1])})(M)
)
#  expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 lapply       32.41ms  32.66ms      30.5   12.48MB    15.2     10     5
#2 lapplyStr_C  26.85ms  27.11ms      36.9   12.48MB    18.4     12     6
#3 matrix       16.28ms  16.94ms      59.4    2.32MB     2.05    29     1
#4 matrixStr_C   7.51ms   7.77ms     127.     2.32MB     6.90    55     3
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `lapply` in base R -

```
asd[-1] <- lapply(asd[-1], function(x) paste0(asd$a, x))
```

Or `across` in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

asd %>% mutate(across(-a, ~str_c(a, .x)))

#  a  b  c
#1 A Ad Ax
#2 B Bf By
```

Answer (score 7):

We can also use the `pmap` function from [`purrr`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/):

```
library(purrr)

asd %>%
  pmap_dfr(~ c(list(...)[1], setNames(paste(..1, c(...)[-1], sep = ""), names(asd)[-1])))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  a     b     c
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     Ad    Ax
2 B     Bf    By
```

Comment: Perhaps link to the (official) documentation for *pmap*?

Comment: Yes of course, thank you for bringing it to my attention. I have to share more links to documentations from now on :)

Answer (score 4):

The function [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) from dplyr makes it easy to apply the same transformation to multiple columns:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(b:c, ~str_c(a, .x))
  )

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   a     b     c    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 A     Ad    Ax   
#> 2 B     Bf    By
```

Comment: Perhaps link to the (official) documentation for 'across'? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: It is not clear how this answer adds anything to Ronak Shah's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68190033/) posted almost two hours earlier.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `apply` in column mode here.  We can define a vector of which columns need to be updated, and then run `apply` only on those columns.

```r
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A","B"), b = c("d","f"), c = c("x","y"))
cols <- c("b", "c")
asd[cols] <- apply(asd[cols], 2, function(x) paste0(asd$a, x))
asd

  a  b  c
1 A Ad Ax
2 B Bf By
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
asd[-1] <- paste0(asd$a[row(asd[-1])], as.matrix(asd[-1]))
```

which gives

```
> asd
  a  b  c
1 A Ad Ax
2 B Bf By
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
asd %>% 
  mutate(b = paste(a,b,sep = ""),
         c = paste(a,c,sep = ""))
```

Try edit

Comment: R is officially supported. Why does the syntax highlighting seem to be off (e.g., there shouldn't be any difference between 'a', 'b', and 'c')?

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68189987/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Odly, nothing changed @PeterMortensen

Comment: @PeterMortensen actually there is. In R, `c`  is actually a function (concatenate), and therefore the syntax highlighting looks like it does.